# Only one write() call sends data over socket connection

Tags: c, linux, ios, sockets, asyncsocket

First stackoverflow question! I've searched...I promise. I haven't found any answers to my predicament. I have...a severely aggravating problem to say the least. To make a very long story short, I am developing the infrastructure for a game where mobile applications (an Android app and an iOS app) communicate with a server using sockets to send data to a database. The back end server script (which I call BES, or Back End Server), is several thousand lines of code long. Essentially, it has a main method that accepts incoming connections to a socket and forks them off, and a method that reads the input from the socket and determines what to do with it. Most of the code lies in the methods that send and receive data from the database and sends it back to the mobile apps. All of them work fine, except for the newest method I have added. This method grabs a large amount of data from the database, encodes it as a JSON object, and sends it back to the mobile app, which also decodes it from the JSON object and does what it needs to do. My problem is that this data is very large, and most of the time does not make it across the socket in one data write. Thus, I added one additional data write into the socket that informs the app of the size of the JSON object it is about to receive. However, after this write happens, the next write sends empty data to the mobile app.

The odd thing is, when I remove this first write that sends the size of the JSON object, the actual sending of the JSON object works fine. It's just very unreliable and I have to hope that it sends it all in one read. To add more oddity to the situation, when I make the size of the data that the second write sends a huge number, the iOS app will read it properly, but it will have the data in the middle of an otherwise empty array.

What in the world is going on? Any insight is greatly appreciated! Below is just a basic snippet of my two write commands on the server side.

Keep in mind that EVERYWHERE else in this script the read's and write's work fine, but this is the only place where I do 2 write operations back to back.

The server script is on a Ubuntu server in native C using Berkeley sockets, and the iOS is using a wrapper class called AsyncSocket.

```
int n;
//outputMessage contains a string that tells the mobile app how long the next message
//(returnData) will be
n = write(sock, outputMessage, sizeof(outputMessage));
if(n < 0)
   //error handling is here
//returnData is a JSON encoded string (well, char[] to be exact, this is native-C)
n = write(sock, returnData, sizeof(returnData));
if(n < 0)
   //error handling is here
```

The mobile app makes two read calls, and gets `outputMessage` just fine, but `returnData` is always just a bunch of empty data, unless I overwrite `sizeof(returnData)` to some hugely large number, in which case, the iOS will receive the data in the middle of an otherwise empty data object (NSData object, to be exact). It may also be important to note that the method I use on the iOS side in my AsyncSocket class reads data up to the length that it receives from the first write call. So if I tell it to read, say 10000 bytes, it will create an NSData object of that size and use it as the buffer when reading from the socket.

Any help is greatly, GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: How do you know write sends something empty(vs your reading app being buggy)  ? This sounds more like the common problem of not accounting for that TCP is stream oriented, not packet oriented. one write() might need many read() calls to receive and vice versa. You need to account for that, no matter how things look on the lab.

Comment: I'm not sure what the original problem was, but it's been remedied by switching to using an `iovec` struct and using `writev` instead of `write`. You're right in that it actually WASN'T writing something empty. The `write` return result was always the correct amount of bytes. The only way I could even get the client to see that it read ANY data was to make the buffer HUGE that the client put the read data into, and somehow, literally in the middle of that buffer, was the data. It was odd. But now I'm reading it until it receives a null terminator and sending it over the socket as an `iovec`.

Comment: If that's the case, it's only being "fixed" in your test cases. Some day, some users will have a slow connection, a very congested connection, or you'll send data fast/read data slow by chance, and you(or more likely an unsuspecting user) will experience the same problem again. read carefully what Greg replied

Comment: @nos he is writing the size of the packet first, I presume this is so he can convert the stream like TCP into a packet, so he reads the size then reads the entire packet specified by the size. If he is doing this then the clients should not be affected by fragmentation. He is now atomically writing the size then the payload, so interleaving writes will not corrupt the "stream".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It's just very unreliable and I have to hope that it sends it all in one read.

The key to successful programming with TCP is that there is no concept of a TCP "packet" or "block" of data at the application level. The application only sees a *stream* of bytes, with no boundaries. When you call `write()` on the sending end with some data, the TCP layer may choose to slice and dice your data in any way it sees fit, including coalescing multiple blocks together.

You might write 10 bytes two times and read 5 then 15 bytes. Or maybe your receiver will see 20 bytes all at once. What you *cannot* do is just "hope" that some chunks of bytes you send will arrive at the other end in the same chunks.

What might be happening in your specific situation is that the two back-to-back writes are being coalesced into one, and your reading logic simply can't handle that.

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like exactly what is happening.  Check the return value of `read()` on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of the feedback! I incorporated everyone's answers into the solution. I created a method that writes to the socket an `iovec` struct using `writev` instead of `write`. The wrapper class I'm using on the iOS side, AsyncSocket (which is fantastic, by the way...check it out here -->[AsyncSocket Google Code Repo](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) ) handles receiving an iovec just fine, and behind the scenes apparently, as it does not require any additional effort on my part for it to read all of the data correctly. The AsyncSocket class does not call my delegate method `didReadData` now until it receives all of the data specified in the `iovec` struct.

Again, thank you all! This helped greatly. Literally overnight I got responses for an issue I've been up against for a week now. I look forward to becoming more involved in the stackoverflow community!

Sample code for solution:

```
//returnData is the JSON encoded string I am returning
//sock is my predefined socket descriptor
struct iovec iov[1];
int iovcnt = 0;
iov[0].iov_base = returnData;
iov[0].iov_len = strlen(returnData);
iovcnt = sizeof(iov) / sizeof(struct iovec);
n = writev(sock, iov, iovcnt)
if(n < 0)
   //error handling here
while(n < iovcnt)
   //rebuild iovec struct with remaining data from returnData (from position n to the end of the string)
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant, You need two entries in the iovec, the first is the size of returnData, the second is actually the returnData. On the client you receive first the size then you read until you have read all the data specified by that size. This converts the stream-like nature of TCP to packets. Also you can send the first size as a 4 byte integer in network byte order using htonl() rather than a string.

Comment: Hey Jim. I'm looking back through old Stackoverflow posts and realized I never finished out this discussion. Also I realize how rookie I was when I wrote this 2 years ago lol. I did what your comment mentioned in the long run, I have two properties in my iovec, the first being the size and the second being the actual data, and the logic on the client side continues to read from the socket until the data it has received reaches the size specified. Thanks again for the direction on this!

Answer (score 0):

You should really define a function `write_complete` that completely writes a buffer to a socket. Check the return value of `write`, it might also be a positive number, but smaller than the size of the buffer. In that case you need to `write` the remaining part of the buffer again.

Oh, and using `sizeof` is error-prone, too. In the above `write_complete` function you should therefore print the given size and compare it to what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally on the server you want to write the header (the size) and the data atomically, I'd do that using the scatter/gather calls `writev()` also if there is any chance multiple threads can write to the same socket concurrently you may want to use a mutex in the write call.

`writev()` will also write all the data before returning (if you are using blocking I/O).

On the client you may have to have a state machine that reads the length of the buffer then sits in a loop reading until all the data has been received, as large buffers will be fragmented and come in in various sized blocks.

Comment: I changed my server side code to use writev instead of write, and put the character buffer to be written into the iovec struct and it worked great! The wrapper class I'm using on the iOS side, AsyncSocket, seems to handle receiving the iovec struct just fine, and does not call my "didReadData" method until it has received all of the data! This was a HUGE help! Thank you thank you thank you!! I now am a firm believer in stackoverflow :)

Comment: In addition to the writev you MUST make sure you read the entire packet on the client as suggested in the other answers, as I also pointed out in my answer sit in a loop until all bytes for the packet have been read.

Comment: See my additional comment below, you are not doing what I intended, just using writev instead of write is not the point. The only reason that seems to work is that writev writes all the data wheres write will only write as much as can be buffered in the TCP stack.